# What annual maintenance does a dishwasher require?

Tags: maintenance, dishwasher

The house we moved into has a dishwasher, and I am wondering if there are any annual maintenance procedures for it.  In googling, all that I came up with was making sure the spinning propellers are cleaned every now and again and wash it with vinegar occasionally to remove any mildew smells.

This one is probably at least 10 years old and we do not have a manual and the label to identify the make model was probably removed years ago so I do not have any identifying tags to specifically research the brand.

Should I pull it out from the counter, or look for a filter to clear, or do I need to oil any parts occasionally aside from the door hinge which I already did?

Or is it best just leave it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dishwashers are intended for permanent installation and there are no parts behind it that you will need to service.

The only things you might want to clean/treat are inside the unit.  Best to leave it alone otherwise.  If you can't remove it easily, it wasn't meant to be removed by household users.

Answer (score 0):

Most dishwashers require you to periodically clean out the filter at the bottom, though some more expensive units might have the equivalent of a built in garburator and not require this.  You should also remove any debris you notice at the bottom.

There are some cleaning tablets you can use on an empty load that will help clean the inside of the dishwasher.  [affresh® Dishwasher Cleaner](http://www.affresh.ca/our_products/affresh_dishwasher_cleaner) is one product that I have used that seems to do a good job.

Otherwise, keep the outside of the unit clean and don't let grease and dirt build up.  Lubricating the door hinge and spring never hurts either, as you already found out.